# Stop adding line endings to file in GIT

Tags: git, vim

My development environment is linux. It seems to be in my repo if I modify a file that is dos format it adds all these line ending changes to the file. So when I try and commit there are large changes to the file rather than just the modification I made. How do I stop this happening i.e. either vim or git ignoring this and not adding these line endings.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole chapter dedicated to that topic in git called autocrlf :

https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace

Comment: Is this the command to leave dos files untouched `git config --global core.autocrlf input`

Comment: Depends what you want to do, you might also use `false` if you don't want to change anything at all. At this point, it is probably easy for you to create a private branch and try it.